# Programmatically checking when the last iCloud backup date was

Tags: ios, icloud

Is it possible to check if the `/Documents` directory in an iOS app have been recently backed up, or if ever at all?

Is this doable without putting explicit support on iCloud?

My app simply stores random stuff in the `/Documents` directory without ever worrying about any iCloud specific functionality or Apple API. Seems like the app data iCloud backup still covers the `/Documents` folder, but it would be nice to be able to tell or warn the user if their data hasn't been backed up to iCloud for a while, especially with important app data.